# Jenkins-CVS plugin - Command Aborted during request processing

Tags: jenkins, cvs, jenkins-plugins

The Jenkins build job fails every now and then when trying to update the workspace with latest in CVS with the following error:

```
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building on master in workspace
Using locally configured password for connection to :pserver:myuser@server:/export/home/cvsroot
cvs update -d -P -r HEAD -D 08 Jan 2013 06:29:03 -0500 prjname
ERROR: CVS Command aborted: Aborted during request processing
org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.command.CommandAbortedException: Aborted during request processing
        at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.Client.handleResponse(Client.java:673)
        at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.Client.processRequests(Client.java:598)
        at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.command.update.UpdateCommand.execute(UpdateCommand.java:347)
        at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.Client.executeCommand(Client.java:710)
        at hudson.scm.AbstractCvs$1.invoke(AbstractCvs.java:243)
        at hudson.scm.AbstractCvs$1.invoke(AbstractCvs.java:223)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:842)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:824)
        at hudson.scm.AbstractCvs.perform(AbstractCvs.java:223)
        at hudson.scm.AbstractCvs.checkout(AbstractCvs.java:140)
        at hudson.scm.CVSSCM.checkout(CVSSCM.java:318)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1256)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:589)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:494)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1502)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
ERROR: Cvs task failed
```

If I restart the build the update goes through fine.

- Jenkins Version : 1.478
- Jenkins-CVS Plugin Version : 2.7

Comment: Any pointers or suggestions to get past this issue will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You could add this info to question: How long does it take for it to fail, is it immediate or does it "hang" for a while before getting aborted? Do CVS server side logs show anything? Are there concurrent builds? If you create a test script which repeatedly does the cvs update, without using Jenkins, can you reproduce the error then?

Comment: If you don't know how long it takes before it fails, you could try this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Timestamper

Answer (score 0):

The CommandAbortedException you're seeing is being thrown because the code received an InterruptedIOException.

This signifies that the thread threw an InterruptedException whilst trying to communicate with your CVS Server, so either someone has hit the cancel button on your job, or you have a process that's trying to end Java threads.